# FormData everything converting to string even arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, form-data, zod

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('choices', [1, 2, 3])
```

*choices* converted to

```
'1,2,3'
```

And this is sent to node js which fails **zod** valdation because it is expecting array. this also same happens with numbers.

axios post request

```
axios.post('product', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
```

Comment: Could you share the code about how you send a request?

Comment: @NickVu I added the post request. Also I need to mention that I sending File and data with request

Comment: Hmm if your `Content-Type` is different, we can pass an object in the payload, but seemingly you're sending files along with it, so we should format those strings on the server side again. The document here is also telling FormData gets formatted to strings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: @NickVu Maybe is there another way to send files and data. Without using FormData

Comment: Hmm seemingly not (maybe I have not done enough research), but if you still want to avoid server data formats, you can have 2 separate calls, one is to upload files, and another is to send data. In this way, you can improve your UX a bit, because you don't block data updates with file upload

Comment: @NickVu So how I understand I should create two endpoints one for file upload and second for data?

Comment: yuppp, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

The value for formData will be converted to a string.

See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including
> subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the **value
> is converted to a string**.

You can convert it back on the server side with:

```
const choicesArray = choices.split(',').map(Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const numArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(numArray));
```

Post request

```
 await axios.post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
```